# Script to write dates from google sheets to calendar

Tags: google-apps-script

First thank you for helping me on my journey to coding...

Im stuck on another small script I need for my organisation

My google sheet is something like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oJ-6fjPym-anjccC5UB_ifWJiES1ci8wrnbmxMOrryk/edit?usp=sharing)

I am looking to write a script that when the contract date is updated then a google calendar event is created.

My Script reads like this:

```js
function contractEndDates() {
  var contractExpiryCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("MY_CALENDER _ID");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var contractural = ss.getSheetByName("ContractEndDate");
  var contractEndValue = contractural.getRange("D2:D").getValues();
    contractEndValue.forEach(([d]) => {
    if (d != null) {
    var rng = contractural.getRange("A:C").getValues();  
    rng.forEach(function(entry){
    contractExpiryCalendar.createAllDayEvent(entry[2],entry[1]);
  }); 
    }
  }
  )
}
```

```html
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

I only want the scrpit to run if there actually is a contract end present
I will install an on edit trigger so that if and when new people are added then a new event is created, however it should not run for all the existing persons.

Hope stack community can help out!

Comment: When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, there are 2 sheets. So I'm confused about understanding your question. I apologize for this. In your script, only `ContractEndDate` sheet is used. From this situation, another sheet `Leave to Calendar` is not related to your question, and you want to use only the sheet `ContractEndDate`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, leave to calendar is another script i am tryting to write currently.  Thank you for your help on the last question..i tried to use the similar forEach function here but somewhere i am going wronf